# Jquery need a toggle function but not sure how

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to create an overlay for when menu item is clicked that has a sub menu. So the submenu will be displayed with an overlay behind it.

I have the following code so far!:

```
//Add overlay to the body and fade it in.
$('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function() {
    $('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2"></div>');
    $('#overlay-2').fadeIn(300);
});

// remove overlay when overlay is clicked
$(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
        $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
            $('#overlay-2').hide();
        });    
    });
});

//close menu when overlay is clicked
$('#overlay-2').click(function(){
    uberMenu_close('#menu-item-1459');
    return false;
});

});
```

This is working great for me however I also want to be able to click on ".jrm-menu-categories" and hide or remove the overlay. This class is for menu items, so it already does the job of hiding the submenu
I was thinking it would be a toggle function but I'm not sure how to go about this. Especially since the first click of ".jrm-menu-categories" inserts the div into the html.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks!!!

### Update

So here is the code I have so far to avoid re-adding the div to the html. But there are some issues. It starts off normal, menu item is clicked..submenu comes down..overlay gets added in. However if I click on the overlay it closes the menu like it should but the overlay doesn't go away. If I reopen the submenu a second time it behaves like it should. I can click on overlay and it will remove the overlay and close the submenu.

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function () {
    var overlay = null; // handle for the overlay

// make sure the overlay doesn't already exist before you create and append
if($("#overlay-2").length === 0) {
    $('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2"></div>');
    $('#overlay-2').fadeIn(300);
    return;
}

overlay = $("#overlay-2");

if (overlay.is(":visible")) {
    overlay.click(function() {
        $('#overlay-2').remove();
    });
} // trigger a click to make it go away
}        
);


// remove overlay when overlay is clicked
// $(function(){// document.ready shorthand
    //   $(document).on('click','#overlay-2',function() {
        //     $('#overlay-2').fadeOut('3000',function(){//use 3000 in place of 300m
        //       $('#overlay-2').hide();
        //});    
    //});
// });


//open the menu when clicking on a special button
$('#overlay-2').click(function(){
    uberMenu_close('#menu-item-1459');
        return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Not sure why you are adding and removing the overlay. Why not always add the overlay (it's only one line of HTML) and then fading it in/out with jQuery?

Comment: The issue you are seeing if because of the visibility check of the overlay. When you define you a function within the $.click() method of jQuery you are binding an event. When you just call $.click(), you are triggering the event. The first time, it doesn't work because you create a binding. It works after that, because the binding is already in place. It is also still more efficient to create the item once and toggle its visibility, than it is to remove and re-add again and again.

Comment: Ill tell you why @BramVanroy , because I'm a total newbie and it never occured to me. I like to complicate things but prefer less compicated routes. Clear as mud? Haha. I'm working on adding in the div and then just creating a toggle function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're fading the menu out, and then re-adding it? That seems really inefficient if the user clicks on the menu multiple times; you'll end up with multiple overlays on the page, non-unique ids, bloating, etc. You can do a couple of things to accomplish what you need. You'll need to add some more functionality to your jrm-menu-categories click method:

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories').click(function () {
    var overlay = null; // handle for the overlay

    // make sure the overlay doesn't already exist before you create and append
    if($("#overlay-2").length === 0) {
        $('#wrap_all').append('<div id="overlay-2"></div>');
        $('#overlay-2').on('click', function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(300);
        }).fadeIn(300);
        return;
    }

    overlay = $("#overlay-2");

    if (overlay.is(":visible")) {
        overlay.click(); // trigger a click to make it go away
    }       
    else {
        overlay.fadeIn(300);
    } 
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38sRc/)

Here is a modded [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38sRc/1/) to handle document click.

Comment: I'll preface with "I'm a real beginner"..   So I looked in firebug and understand what you mean about re-adding it in. I tried your code but it seems to have broken some functionality (error on my part I'm sure) See upadted post above

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle to show the html and other JS that might be interacting on the page?

Comment: I edited my answer to bind the onclick method, which should give you what you need.

Comment: Opps just saw you comment